# Is there a word to collectively refer to "the things on the office table"

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, collective-nouns

For example, "Confectionaries" is to refer to all kinds of candy. I'm looking for a word to describe all sorts of things one might find on the office table (pen, paper, paper clips etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Office paraphernalia* might work.

Answer (score 2):

Stationery might work. It mainly means paper and writing implements, but it can also mean staplers etc.

Comment: Can you improve your answer by providing some support such as an example of stationery being used in such a broad way?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I believe that you’re talking about a ***desk***. 
An office would have *tables* in conference rooms (for meetings) and for food,
but these tables generally wouldn’t have pens, paper clips, etc., on them
(except, perhaps, during meetings).

I can’t think of a good *single (collective) word* for those items,
but ***office supplies*** seems to be a very common phrase.

[image]

Comment: Right. I was just finding it hard to describe. I was really looking for the term to refer to "things used to perform an activity" and I remember "paraphernalia" used in conjunction with "office supplies". A tip of the tongue moment :) @KWinker solved it